# Hide the standard AddThis tooltip and images

Tags: css, image, tooltip, title, addthis

AddThis always places its standard images and tooltips on share buttons. I want to completely customize AddThis, and hide tooltips and images. Because I want to load my bouncing images by my JavaScript and no tooltips. I set the following config to prevent standard CSS of AddThis.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {ui_use_css: false}</script>
```

But how to prevent tooltips and images?
I know, that when you set your own **title** and **img** attributes, it shows yours instead of the standard AddThis title/image, but I want to completely hide tooltips and images. As I said, all images will be loaded by my script:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook" title=" ">Facebook</a>
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by this way.

To prevent AddThis tooltips completely I added

```
 title="&nbsp;"
```

Note that title="" or title=" " will not work.

To prevent standard images I added an empty  tag. So the complete code will be:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook" title="&nbsp;">Facebook<img></a>
```

Now AddThis saw your  tag and title attribute, so does not substitute them.